# what can i do, i can't install wine

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, wine

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you haverequested an 
impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required 
packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recall when I installed Wine on my Ubuntu machine (14.04) that I had trouble as well. There were two packages in the Ubuntu Software Center:

- Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package)
- Wine Windows Program Loader

I think it was the 2nd one that actually worked to get the whole package installed.

EDIT: Check out this answer which explains how to add the Wine PPA: [Why should I prefer ppa wine over the wine in the official repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306690/why-should-i-prefer-ppa-wine-over-the-wine-in-the-official-repository)

Comment: i cant download it

Comment: I added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.    ???